# Create URL hyperlink in R Shiny?

Tags: r, hyperlink, shiny

My code:

```
library(shiny)
runApp(
  list(ui = fluidPage(
     uiOutput("tab")
    ),
  server = function(input, output, session){
    url <- a("Google Homepage", href="https://www.google.com/")
    output$tab <- renderUI({
      paste("URL link:", url)
    })
  })
)
```

Current output:

`URL link: <a href="https://www.google.com/">Google Homepage</a>`

Desired output:

`URL link: Google Homepage`

where `Google Homepage` is a clickable hyperlink.

I'm currently using the `renderUI`/`uiOutput` duo as instructed here: [how to create a hyperlink interactively in shiny app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25818416/how-to-create-a-hyperlink-interactively-in-shiny-app)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

By using `paste`, you're treating the `url` as a string. The function you want to use here is `tagList`:

```
runApp(
  list(ui = fluidPage(
     uiOutput("tab")
    ),
  server = function(input, output, session){
    url <- a("Google Homepage", href="https://www.google.com/")
    output$tab <- renderUI({
      tagList("URL link:", url)
    })
  })
)
```

Comment: How to ensure the url link is opened inside the SHiny app and not a new tab?

Answer (score 29):

You can use html tags whatever you want to  [tag](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/tag-glossary.html)

```
    tags$a(href="www.rstudio.com", "Click here!")
## <a href="www.rstudio.com">Click here!</a>
```

Comment: Also, to open it in a new browser, adding  target="_blank"  as argument.

Comment: would you know how to change the font size if we use your tags$a solution? Thanks