# Making multiple images hyperlinked in Shiny

Tags: html, r, hyperlink, shiny

Let's say I have a input `data frame` as below:

```
dat <- data.frame(
    country = c('USA', 'China', 'UK', "Germany", "France"),                                             
    flag = c('<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/a/a4/Flag_of_the_United_States.svg/200px-Flag_of_the_United_States.svg.png" width="100" height="80"></img>', '<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fa/Flag_of_the_People%27s_Republic_of_China.svg/200px-Flag_of_the_People%27s_Republic_of_China.svg.png"width="100" height="80"></img>', '<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/ae/Flag_of_the_United_Kingdom.svg"width="100" height="80"></img>', '<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/ba/Flag_of_Germany.svg"width="100" height="80"></img>', '<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/c/c3/Flag_of_France.svg"width="100" height="80"></img>'),                                                    
    infolink = c('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States', 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/China', 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Kingdom', 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germany', 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/France'))
```

My original `data frame` is large. Data frame has 3 columns `country`, `flag`, and `infolink`. Column `country` has name of country. Column `flag` has an image source of the flag which will be displayed. And, column `infolink` has url to country's wikipedia page. My goal is to display a flag of country with the country name in `datatable` format using `renderDataTable`. Where, flag of each country shall be hyper-linked to it's respective wikipedia url in infolink column.

There are multiple SO questions already asked on hyperlinking an image:

[Making an Image Hyperlink in R Shiny header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38558827/making-an-image-hyperlink-in-r-shiny-header)

[how to create a hyperlink interactively in shiny app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25818416/how-to-create-a-hyperlink-interactively-in-shiny-app)

However, these questions hyperlink one image source not multiple images with respective to their hyperlink.

Following is my shiny app code:

```
library(shiny)
# UI for application
ui <- fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("Image Hyperlinking Test"),

   mainPanel(
     a(dataTableOutput("imagetest"), href=dat$infolink, target="_blank")
   )
)

# Server for application
server <- function(input, output) {
  a(dat$flag, href=dat$infolink)
  dat2 <- data.frame(dat[,c("country", "flag")])

  output$imagetest <- renderDataTable({
    return(dat2)
  },escape = FALSE) 
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Running this app is producing two warnings:

```
Warning in if (!is.na(attribValue)) { :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used Warning in charToRaw(enc2utf8(text)) :
argument should be a character vector of length 1 all but the first element will be ignored
```

I understand that these warnings is caused by `href` in ui because I assigned `vector` of hyperlinks greater than 1 and its only assigning first hyperlink to all images. This is giving me an app dashboard as below:

[image]

However, every flag is hyperlinked to the first `hyperlink` in a vector as it was suggested in the warning. So, if I click on each flag, it's redirecting me to the wikipedia page of USA which is a first `hyperlink` in infolink vector in my dat `data frame`.

I tried several things to fix the warning and hyperlink every flag to their respective country's wikipedia page but nothing worked. If I missed any SO post which cover this, I would be glad if you redirect me to it. Anyhow, I would appreciate any guide to fix this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
 dat <- data.frame(
      country = c('USA', 'China', 'UK', "Germany", "France"),                                             
      flag = c('<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/a/a4/Flag_of_the_United_States.svg/200px-Flag_of_the_United_States.svg.png" width="100" height="80"></img>', '<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fa/Flag_of_the_People%27s_Republic_of_China.svg/200px-Flag_of_the_People%27s_Republic_of_China.svg.png"width="100" height="80"></img>', '<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/ae/Flag_of_the_United_Kingdom.svg"width="100" height="80"></img>', '<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/ba/Flag_of_Germany.svg"width="100" height="80"></img>', '<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/c/c3/Flag_of_France.svg"width="100" height="80"></img>'),                                                    
      infolink = c('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States', 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/China', 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Kingdom', 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germany', 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/France'),
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

    library(shiny)
    # UI for application
    ui <- fluidPage(

      # Application title
      titlePanel("Image Hyperlinking Test"),

      mainPanel(
        DT::dataTableOutput("imagetest")#, href=dat$infolink, target="_blank")
      )
    )

    # Server for application
    server <- function(input, output) {
      hlink <- apply(dat,1, function(x){
       as.character(a(HTML(x[["flag"]]), href=x[["infolink"]], target="_blank"))
      })      

      dat2$link <- hlink
      output$imagetest <- DT::renderDataTable({
        DT::datatable(dat2, escape = FALSE)
      }) 
    }

    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Loved what you did with hlink. I tried similar thing but was not successful to get semantically correct HTML syntax. In your code, `dat2` needs to be `dat` to get the app functional. Also, it would be cool if you can explain briefly this part: `HTML(x[["flag"]]), href=x[["infolink"]]`. Thanks a bunch and I am accepting the answer.

Comment: Basically `a`  tag defines a hyperlink. So `href` specifies the URL of the page the link goes to which is `x[["infolink"]]` the parameter that is displayed . In our case that is the html for displaying the image hence `HTML` function. Hope it is clear.

Comment: Got it. When I wrote similar function, I did not use HTML function and in result it was displaying image source instead of images. Thanks again.